# Find the inverse z- transform of $ X(z)=\frac{z^3+2z^2-2z}{(z-2)(z^2+2)}$

Tags: inverse, z-transform

Find the inverse transform

\begin{equation}
    X(z)=\frac{z^3+2z^2-2z}{(z-2)(z^2+2)}
\end{equation}

We solve  the partial fractions for:

\begin{equation}
  \frac{X(z)}{z}=\frac{z^2+2z-2}{(z-2)(z^2+2)}=z\bigg(\frac{1}{z-2}+\frac{2}{2+z^2}\bigg)
\end{equation}

We now have to inverse transform:

\begin{equation} 
\frac{z}{z-2}+\frac{2z}{2+z^2}
\end{equation}

From the table we have:

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}
     -\frac{z}{z-2} \rightarrow 2^{n}\\
     \frac{2z}{z^2+2} \rightarrow   ?
\end{array}
\end{equation}

For the last transform, I did the partial fractions decomposition on it and got

\begin{equation*}
   \frac{2z}{z^2+2} = \frac{\big(1+\frac{\sqrt{2}i}{4}\big)}{z-\sqrt{2}i}+\frac{\big(1-\frac{\sqrt{2}i}{4}\big)}{z+\sqrt{2}i}
\end{equation*}

Using the Residue theorem:

\begin{equation}
    Res(-\sqrt{2}i)=\lim_{z\rightarrow -\sqrt{2}i}(z-\sqrt{2}i)\frac{\big(1+\frac{\sqrt{2}i}{4}\big)}{z-\sqrt{2}i}z^{n-1}=(1+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}i)(-\sqrt{2}i)^{n-1}
\end{equation}

and

\begin{equation}
    Res(\sqrt{2}i)=\lim_{z\rightarrow \sqrt{2}i}(z+\sqrt{2}i)\frac{\big(1-\frac{\sqrt{2}i}{4}\big)}{z+\sqrt{2}i}z^{n-1}=(1-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}i)(\sqrt{2}i)^{n-1}
\end{equation}

So

\begin{equation}
    V(n)=(1+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}i)(-\sqrt{2}i)^{n-1}+(1-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}i)(\sqrt{2}i)^{n-1}-2^n
\end{equation}

But Wolframalpha shows something quite different: [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=inverse%20Z%20transform%20calculator%20of%20%5Cfrac%7Bz%5E3%2B2z%5E2-2z%7D%7B%28z-2%29%28z%5E2%2B2%29%7D)
which appears as this:

[image]

while my solution appears as this:

[image]

Comment: For example $(z - 2)(z^2  + 2) = z^3  - 2z^2  + 2z - 4$ just to mention one.

Comment: $$
\frac{{6z}}{{z^2  + 2z - 2}} = \frac{{3 - \sqrt 3 }}{{z - \sqrt 3  + 1}} + \frac{{3 + \sqrt 3 }}{{z + \sqrt 3  + 1}}
$$

Comment: Never multiply out the brackets in the denominator, the factored form is already there. Do partial fractions not on $X(z)$ but on $\frac{X(z)}{z}$, then when you are finished multiply back through by $z$ again.

Comment: Got it, so I ended with $X(z)=-\frac{z}{z-2}+z\frac{2z-1}{z^2+2}$. The former was easily converted to $-2^n$. But for the latter, I didn't know which table entry to use, so I used partial fractions again with complex entries and finally Cauchys theorem

Comment: @Paul I made an update

Comment: I got $\frac{X}{z}=\frac{1}{z-2}+\frac{2}{z^2+2}$ so that $X=\frac{z}{z-2}+\frac{2z}{z^2+2}$

Comment: Yes, me too, after that I am not sure what went wrong.